# On the eigenvalues of a linear transformation $\tau$ such that $\tau^3 = \mathrm{id}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading  the book on representation theory by Fulton and Harris in GTM.  I came across this paragraph.

> [..] we will start our analysis of an arbitrary representation $W$ of $S_3$ by looking just at the action of the abelian subgroup $\mathfrak A_3 = \mathbb Z/3 \subset \mathfrak S_3$ on $W$. This yields a very simple decomposition: if we take $\tau$ to be any generator of $\mathfrak A_3$ (that is, any three-cycle), the space $W$ is spanned by eigenvectors $v_i$ for the action of $\tau$, whose eivenvalues are of course all powers of a cube root of unity $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}.$

I know the eigenvalues of $\tau$ are some cube root of unity, but I don't know why all of the cube roots of unity are eigenvalues of $\tau$.

I tried to calculate the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\tau$.  It is easily seen that $f$ divides $X^3 - 1$, but I cannot go further in this regard, since I do not know anything about $W$ except the fact that it is finite-dimensional.

I would be most grateful if you could help me understand the paragraph.

Comment: It sounds to me like the authors are saying the eigenvalues each have the property of being cube roots of unity, NOT that ALL cube roots of unity are eigenvalues.

Comment: Seems like this question really belongs to english.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: This is a great example of bad mathematical writing. On the other hand, I don't think we should be too hard on the authors --- the same construction in usual English (with the same sense) is generally very clear. Consider "The mathematicians are all Luddites"; would one ever interpret that as meaning that every Luddite is a mathematician? Yet somehow in a mathematical context, this construction becomes much less clear.

Comment: I am reading the same books at the moment and that's the second question at math.stackexchange.com where this book is quoted and one doesn't understand what is the text really about (including myself). Sure authors assume that you master mathematical language, but some explanation wouldn't harm.

Comment: How are we calculating the minimal polynomial of $\tau$ if we don't know how $\tau$ acts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last sentence is remarkably ambiguous: I can stare at it and watch my perception of its meaning flicker back and forth between "Every eigenvalue of $\tau$ is a power of $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/3}$ and "The eigenvalues of $\tau$ give all of the powers of $\omega$."

Mathematically it is the former which is true -- as the authors very well know -- so that is the intended meaning.  It is enough to observe that a complex representation of the cyclic group $C_3 = \langle \tau \ | \ \tau^3 = 1 \rangle$ need not have $\omega$ as an eigenvalue.  For instance, there is always the trivial representation, whose only eigenvalue is $1$.  More generally $C_3$ has precisely $3$ irreducible complex representations: they are all one-dimensional and consist of scaling by $1$, $\omega$ or $\omega^2$.  By taking direct sums of these -- or, in simpler terms, taking a diagonal matrix with whatever combination of $1,\omega,\omega^2$ you want on the diagonal -- you can get whatever eigenvalues you want (among cube roots of $1$!) with whatever multiplicities.

That's over $\mathbb{C}$.  If we are working over a subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ which doesn't contain a primitive cube root of unity -- e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ or any of its subfields, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ -- then in any representation in which $\omega$ appears as an eigenvalue, so also must $\omega^2$.  There are lots of ways to see this, but perhaps the most purely representation-theoretic is to notice that instead of three one-dimensional irreducible representations of $C_3$, in this case there is the trivial (one-dimensional) representation and an irreducible two-dimensional representation with irreducible minimal polynomial $t^2+t+1$.  And this comes, for instance, from decomposing the group ring $K[C_3]$ into a product of simple rings:

$K[C_3] \cong K[t]/(t^3-1) = K[t]/((t-1)(t^2+t+1))$

$ \cong K[t]/(t-1) \oplus K[t]/(t^2+t+1) \cong K \oplus K[\omega]$.

Comment: The authors also mention that the space $W$ is spanned by the eigenvectors for the action of $\tau$. How then do we know that $W$ has a basis of eigenvectors?

Answer (score 5):

"All eigenvalues are powers of $\omega$" is not the same as "All powers of $\omega$ are eigenvalues".

Comment: My mother tongue not being English, I thought the word "all" in the phrase "whose eivenvalues are of course all powers of a cube root of unity" modifies "powers", not "eigenvalues" :-(  Regarding the mathematical content of the issue, is there a counterexample of such $\tau$ that not all of the powers of $\omega$ are its eignevalues?

Comment: I understand your problem. The identity linear transformation $I$ is an example of what you are looking for.